# Simplest way to say "$\varphi$ is a wff of formal system $\mathbf{F}$"?

Tags: logic, notation, formal-systems

What is the simplest way to say "$\varphi$ is a well-formed formula of formal system $\mathbf{F}$" in symbols? The only thing that comes to mind is:
$$\varphi \in \mathbf{F}$$

Am I right?

I.e., would it be acceptable to say (somewhat cumbersomely):
$$'\exists x (x=x)'\in \mathbf{ZFC}$$

Comment: It depends on the definition of [Formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have the most common definition in mind.

Comment: Usually, a [Formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) **F** is made of : (i) an *alphabet* (set of *symbols*); (ii) a *grammar*, i.e. a set of rules specifying the well-formed expressions; (iii) a set of *axioms*; (iv) a set of *inference rules*. If so, to say $\varphi \in$ **F** is ambiguous.

Comment: Your definition will be correct provided a formal system is a set of wffs.  I do not think that is the most common definition.  Why do you need to say "φ is a well-formed formula of formal system F" in symbols?  Would it not be getter (and clearer) to say it in words?

Comment: The simplest and best way is this: "$\phi$ is a wff of the formal system $F$".